# Customize input with radio type in bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to make input with type radio and i want to customize my radio input to become like this:
[image]

here's my html

```
<form class="size-option">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">S
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">M
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">XL
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
```

here's my scss

```
.size-option {
  .form-check {
    border: 1px solid $clr-black;
    margin: 0;
  .form-check-label {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .form-check-input {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
 }
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you, not exactly what you are looking for but almost similar. make the necessary changes as you wish.( FYI:added jquery support )

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qLnsb9duvnZULotJDN6R?p=preview)

```
 <div class="thing">
      <div  data-toggle="buttons">
        <label data-toggle="radio-tab-label" data-focus-target="true" data-target="#option1" class=" mr-4 btn btn-primary" tabindex="0">
          <input type="radio" value="One" name="options" id="option1" checked> S
        </label>
        <label data-toggle="radio-tab-label" data-focus-target="true" data-target="#option2" class="mr-4 btn btn-primary" tabindex="0">
          <input type="radio" value="Onea" name="options" id="option2"> M
        </label>
        <label data-toggle="radio-tab-label" data-focus-target="true" data-target="#option3" class=" mr-4 btn btn-primary" tabindex="0">
          <input type="radio" value="Ones" name="options" id="option3"> XL
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```